# what is "[Error] expected unqualified-Id before 'if'" mean in this block of code

Tags: c++

I am trying to measure savings as an example for a school project and I really don't know what I did wrong of course adding the if statement inside the function will not work since it can't call itself

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
 struct worker{
    int salary;
    float taxperc;
    int bills;
    int home_needs;
    int bonus;
    bool measure;
    void saving(){
        float tax = (salary/100)*taxperc;
        cout << salary - tax -bills-home_needs  << endl;
    }
    if (measure)
        saving();
};
worker me = {50000, 2.5, 150, 3000, 0, true};
}
```

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you cannot have an `if` at the `struct` scope level. Directly in `struct { ... }` you can only have:

- member values (fields)
- member functions

and not a regular code, statements, etc. When would you actually expect such code to be executed?

Your options are:

- put `if (measure) { saving(); }` into the another member function
- invoke `saving()` from outside the struct, in your `main` function, e.g. `me.saving()`

P.S. I strongly suggest you work on indentation of your code too, for readability sake.

Comment: @Xyz: Which book are you using?

Comment: im not using any, I'm trying to be self-taught